# Make duplicate row number by columns ID SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have trouble from below problem. I have a table that display the records of rooms booked by my customer. I would like to display the RowNum as showed from my Expected Result but instead I got the
wrong result (actual result)

My SQL query:

```
select  customer.customer_id, room.Room_ID , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY room.Room_ID desc) As RowNum
From customer customer
LEFT JOIN room room
    on customer.room_id = room.room_id
```

**Expected Result:**

```
customer_id,   Room_ID ,  RowNum
1,              B01,      1
2,              B01,      1
3,              B01,      1
4,              B02,      2
5,              B03,      3
6,              B04,      4
7,              B04,      4
8,              B05,      5
9,              B06,      6
```

**Actual Result**

```
Customer_ID,   Room_ID,  RowNum
1,              B01,      1
2,              B01,      2
3,              B01,      3
4,              B02,      4
5,              B03,      5
6,              B04,      6
7,              B04,      7
8,              B05,      8
9,              B06,      9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` as follows:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY room.Room_ID desc) As RowNum
```

Comment: Thanks. I never thought of using DESE_RANK(). It works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Given the expected result, you might want to `PARTITION BY` the `Room_ID`. That means the row count starts freshly for each encountered `Room_ID`.

The [ORACLE Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) covers this in full beauty.